# Themes folder path changes

Tags: javascript, theming

I am developing a site, in which my client has only access to sites/default/files path(their company allows only this path as public) today i got a new requirement that theme files such as css and js needs to be editable by admin , so they want theme files in sites/default/files/themes/site-theme. Is this achievable ? if so please give me any ideas on this .

Comment: When you say editable by admin, do you mean by a Drupal admin through the Drupal interface?  If so, this sounds like a recipe for disaster.  Are you using a version control workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to alter the `$theme_path` global during `hook_init()`, although that would mean that *all* your theme files should be in another directory. I'm not sure if that's what you're going for.

If you just want to change some paths (ie for the stylesheets), alter the paths during `hook_preprocess_page()`, look up `$vars['styles']` and change the paths there.